# Could not build released APK

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter, gradle, dart

my flutter application is worked fine with `flutter run` but when i come to build an APK it failed
with an error

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'android_intent'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an > ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

i don't know what a `android_intent` and i tried everything but i couldn't solve it

im using

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    // Add the google services classpath
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
}
```

and my `locale.properties` is that

```
sdk.dir=E:\\development\\android-sdk
flutter.sdk=E:\\development\\flutter
flutter.buildMode=release
flutter.versionName=1.3.0
```

and my `sitting.gradle` contains `include ':app'` at the top

any way i could build my sdk ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gives the error of you not having an environment variable set up, try this:

```
MyComputer -> Properties -> Advanced sys settings -> Environment Variables ->
```

Add ANDROID_HOME=C:...\android-sdk_folder

Also there may be a problem with one of your packages. Make sure they are all up to date.

Comment: i removed unused packages and it works, thank you very much!!